# Creating an SSRS Report about the reports on the Report Server

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I am creating an SSRS Report (for documentation purposes) using SQL-Server 2014 about all the Reports we have on our Report Server. I found code online that would help me to do that.

Please see: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Reporting+Services+(SSRS)/152814/?utm_source=SSC&utm_medium=pubemail

The code is as follows:

```
BEGIN TRY
DROP TABLE #ReportList
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

BEGIN TRY
DROP TABLE #ReportParameters
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

BEGIN TRY
DROP TABLE #ReportFields
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

SELECT 
Name
,Path
INTO #ReportList
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog 
WHERE Content IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Name;

 SELECT DISTINCT Name as ReportName
,ParameterName = Paravalue.value('Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ParameterType = Paravalue.value('Type[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ISNullable = Paravalue.value('Nullable[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ISAllowBlank = Paravalue.value('AllowBlank[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ISMultiValue = Paravalue.value('MultiValue[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ISUsedInQuery = Paravalue.value('UsedInQuery[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ParameterPrompt = Paravalue.value('Prompt[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,DynamicPrompt = Paravalue.value('DynamicPrompt[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,PromptUser = Paravalue.value('PromptUser[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,State = Paravalue.value('State[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
INTO #ReportParameters
 FROM (  
SELECT top 1000 C.Name,CONVERT(XML,C.Parameter) AS ParameterXML
FROM  ReportServer.dbo.Catalog C
WHERE  C.Content is not null
AND  C.Type  = 2
 ) a
CROSS APPLY ParameterXML.nodes('//Parameters/Parameter') p ( Paravalue )
ORDER BY ReportName,ParameterName;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS rd )
SELECT DISTINCT ReportName = name
    ,DataSetName = x.value('(@Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
 ,DataSourceName = x.value('(Query/DataSourceName)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
 ,CommandText = x.value('(Query/CommandText)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
 ,Fields = df.value('(@Name)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
 ,DataField = df.value('(DataField)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
 ,DataType = df.value('(rd:TypeName)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
 ,ConnectionString = x.value('(ConnectionProperties/ConnectString)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
INTO #ReportFields
 FROM ( SELECT C.Name,CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),C.Content)) AS reportXML
      FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog C
     WHERE C.Content is not null
      AND C.Type = 2
 ) a
 CROSS APPLY reportXML.nodes('/Report/DataSets/DataSet') r ( x )
 CROSS APPLY x.nodes('Fields/Field') f(df) 
ORDER BY name 

SELECT 
a.Name AS ReportName
,a.Path
,SUBSTRING(a.Path,1,LEN(a.Path)-LEN(a.Name)) AS ReportFolder
,'http://msl-db12/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath='+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(a.Path,1,LEN(a.Path)-LEN(a.Name)),'/','%2f')+REPLACE(a.Name,' ','+') AS ReportLink
,'User Input' AS FieldType
,b.ParameterPrompt AS DataSetOrPromptName
,b.ParameterName AS FieldOrParameterName
FROM #ReportList a
LEFT OUTER JOIN #ReportParameters b ON a.Name = b.ReportName
WHERE b.ParameterName IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT 
a.Name AS ReportName
,a.Path
,SUBSTRING(a.Path,1,LEN(a.Path)-LEN(a.Name)) AS ReportFolder
,'http://msl-db12/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath='+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(a.Path,1,LEN(a.Path)-LEN(a.Name)),'/','%2f')+REPLACE(a.Name,' ','+') AS ReportLink
,'Data Point' AS FieldType
,b.DataSetName AS DataSetOrPromptName
,b.Fields AS FieldOrParameterName
FROM #ReportList a
LEFT OUTER JOIN #ReportFields b ON a.Name = b.ReportName
WHERE b.Fields IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Name,Path,FieldType,ParameterPrompt,ParameterName
```

This code worked great and I got a nice report about all the reports on my report server.

How do I join the subscriptions table to get columns for subscriptions for each report?

I added the following code but that didn't quite work:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS rd )
SELECT 
    DISTINCT ReportName = name
        ,DataSetName = x.value('(@Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
    ,DataSourceName = x.value('(Query/DataSourceName)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
    ,CommandText = x.value('(Query/CommandText)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
    ,Fields = df.value('(@Name)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
    ,DataField = df.value('(DataField)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
    ,DataType = df.value('(rd:TypeName)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
    ,ConnectionString = x.value('(ConnectionProperties/ConnectString)[1]','VARCHAR(250)'
    -------------------------Added this section here.
    ,S.[OwnerID]
    ,S.[Description]
    ,S.LastStatus)
    -------------------------End of the section here.    
INTO #ReportFields

FROM (  SELECT   C.Name
        ,CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),C.Content)) AS reportXML
    -------------------------Added this section here.
        ,S.[OwnerID]
        ,S.[Description]
        ,S.LastStatus
    -------------------------End of the section here.
        FROM [GEB_ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] C
    -------------------------And this section here.     
            INNER JOIN [GEB_ReportServer].[dbo].[Subscriptions] S ON C.ItemID = S.Report_OID
    -------------------------
        WHERE C.Content is not null
          AND C.Type = 2
 ) a

CROSS APPLY reportXML.nodes('/Report/DataSets/DataSet') r ( x )
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('Fields/Field') f(df) 

ORDER BY name
```

I tried the code from the below suggested answer but after it ran, I got an error message:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 77. Invalid object name '#ReportParameters'.

So, I uncommented the -- INTO #ReportParameters  and I got the report to run without errors but it'd didn't give any fields from the Subscriptions table.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work with the code below. This may help you out. The aliases you are using look like they need to be adjusted. Easy to miss, easy to fix. :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name as ReportName
,ParameterName = Paravalue.value('Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ParameterType = Paravalue.value('Type[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ISNullable = Paravalue.value('Nullable[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ISAllowBlank = Paravalue.value('AllowBlank[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ISMultiValue = Paravalue.value('MultiValue[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ISUsedInQuery = Paravalue.value('UsedInQuery[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ParameterPrompt = Paravalue.value('Prompt[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,DynamicPrompt = Paravalue.value('DynamicPrompt[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,PromptUser = Paravalue.value('PromptUser[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,State = Paravalue.value('State[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 

    ,a.[OwnerID]
    ,a.[Description]
    ,a.LastStatus
-- INTO #ReportParameters
 FROM (  
SELECT top 1000 C.Name,CONVERT(XML,C.Parameter) AS ParameterXML
,S.[OwnerID]
,S.[Description]
,S.LastStatus
FROM dbo.Catalog C 
            LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Subscriptions] S ON C.ItemID = S.Report_OID
WHERE  C.Content is not null
AND  C.Type  = 2
 ) a
CROSS APPLY ParameterXML.nodes('//Parameters/Parameter') p ( Paravalue )
ORDER BY ReportName,ParameterName;
```

EDIT:

Complete solution below

```
SELECT 
C.Name
,C.Path
,S.[OwnerID]
,S.[Description]
,S.LastStatus
INTO #ReportList
FROM dbo.Catalog C LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Subscriptions] S ON C.ItemID = S.Report_OID
WHERE Content IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Name;

 SELECT DISTINCT Name as ReportName
,ParameterName = Paravalue.value('Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ParameterType = Paravalue.value('Type[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ISNullable = Paravalue.value('Nullable[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ISAllowBlank = Paravalue.value('AllowBlank[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ISMultiValue = Paravalue.value('MultiValue[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ISUsedInQuery = Paravalue.value('UsedInQuery[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,ParameterPrompt = Paravalue.value('Prompt[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,DynamicPrompt = Paravalue.value('DynamicPrompt[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,PromptUser = Paravalue.value('PromptUser[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
  ,State = Paravalue.value('State[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
INTO #ReportParameters
 FROM (  
SELECT top 1000 C.Name,CONVERT(XML,C.Parameter) AS ParameterXML

FROM  dbo.Catalog C
WHERE  C.Content is not null
AND  C.Type  = 2
 ) a
CROSS APPLY ParameterXML.nodes('//Parameters/Parameter') p ( Paravalue )
ORDER BY ReportName,ParameterName;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS rd )
SELECT DISTINCT ReportName = name
    ,DataSetName = x.value('(@Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
 ,DataSourceName = x.value('(Query/DataSourceName)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
 ,CommandText = x.value('(Query/CommandText)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
 ,Fields = df.value('(@Name)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
 ,DataField = df.value('(DataField)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
 ,DataType = df.value('(rd:TypeName)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
 ,ConnectionString = x.value('(ConnectionProperties/ConnectString)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')

INTO #ReportFields
 FROM ( SELECT C.Name,CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),C.Content)) AS reportXML
      FROM dbo.Catalog C 
     WHERE C.Content is not null
      AND C.Type = 2
 ) a
 CROSS APPLY reportXML.nodes('/Report/DataSets/DataSet') r ( x )
 CROSS APPLY x.nodes('Fields/Field') f(df) 
ORDER BY name 

SELECT 
a.Name AS ReportName
,a.Path
,a.[OwnerID]
,a.[Description]
,a.LastStatus
,SUBSTRING(a.Path,1,LEN(a.Path)-LEN(a.Name)) AS ReportFolder
,'http://msl-db12/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath='+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(a.Path,1,LEN(a.Path)-LEN(a.Name)),'/','%2f')+REPLACE(a.Name,' ','+') AS ReportLink
,'User Input' AS FieldType
,b.ParameterPrompt AS DataSetOrPromptName
,b.ParameterName AS FieldOrParameterName
FROM #ReportList a
LEFT OUTER JOIN #ReportParameters b ON a.Name = b.ReportName
WHERE b.ParameterName IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT 
a.Name AS ReportName
,a.Path
,a.[OwnerID]
,a.[Description]
,a.LastStatus
,SUBSTRING(a.Path,1,LEN(a.Path)-LEN(a.Name)) AS ReportFolder
,'http://msl-db12/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath='+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(a.Path,1,LEN(a.Path)-LEN(a.Name)),'/','%2f')+REPLACE(a.Name,' ','+') AS ReportLink
,'Data Point' AS FieldType
,b.DataSetName AS DataSetOrPromptName
,b.Fields AS FieldOrParameterName
FROM #ReportList a
LEFT OUTER JOIN #ReportFields b ON a.Name = b.ReportName
WHERE b.Fields IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Name,Path,FieldType,ParameterPrompt,ParameterName


DROP TABLE #ReportList
DROP TABLE #ReportParameters
DROP TABLE #ReportFields
```

Comment: I was so happy when this started to run and started to show the list of records. But after it ran, I got an error message: Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 77. Invalid object name '#ReportParameters'.  Please can you help resolve that? So close to have this report complete._______>>> Your code commented out the -- INTO #ReportParameters line.......   I uncommented it and I got the report to run.  Is that the solution?

Comment: I would say that if this is working now, then it is the solution. I commented out that `INTO #ReportParameters` so I could at least test what I posted. If you need that in your overall code set, then you should be good I think.

Comment: It works without giving me an error BUT I don't get any of the Subscription Table fields. So, No, it doesn't really work. I really appreciate your trying to help though.

Comment: I updated the answer with the full solution. I just ran this against my SSRS DB and it seemed to work well. I hope it meets your expectations.

Comment: That was friggin' AWESOME!!! That sure worked. However, there is only one more issue. The OwnerID is basically an ID. I wish I could join the Users table ON OwnerID = Users.UserID and show Users.UserName instead in the results.___  But you've been a great help so far. Thank you very very much!!!

Comment: Why wish... just add the join to Users and get what you need!

Comment: I joined the Users table and got the report to show the username instead. Worked great! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You bet! Glad to hear you got it working how you need it to.